# Why priority queue is implemented using heaps when we can implement it using just vector more efficiently

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, implementation

Why is `priority_queue` implemented using heaps when without using heaps too we can implement it with just vectors.

Suppose we use vector as a queue and keep the elements in decreasing order. 
We can use this as priority queue.

For insertion: We can use binary search. `Complexity O(logN)`

For deletion: Here also we can use binary search. `Complexity O(logN)`

For top element: `O(1)`

In addition, we can have access kth maximum element in just `O(1)` time which is not the case with heaps.

Then, why do we use heaps for implementing priority queues?

Comment: How does binary  search insert anything?

Comment: Oh! that thing I forgot

Comment: Downvotes seem so unnecessary here.

Comment: StackOverflow's [just posted](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/) a blog entry about how the site doesn't seem very welcoming. People's response to this question is like a case in point. @prashantshishodia: I am sorry you have experienced this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For insertion : We can use binary search . Complexity O(logN)
>
> For deltion : Here also we can use binary search. Complexity O(logN)

No, you can't. By using a sorted array/vector you can only search for the correct index on `O(log N)` but to do the actual insert or delete you have to shift other elements which is `O(N)`.

Comment: Oh! got it  , my mistake

Answer (score 0):

The default priority queue *does use* `std::vector`. It layers the *heap algorithms* over that to get the required performance characteristics.

A sketch implementation:

```
template <typename T>
class priority_queue
{
    std::vector<T> elems;
public:
    std::vector<T>::const_reference top() const { 
         return elems.front(); // O(1)
    }
    void push( const T& value ) { 
         elems.push_back(value); // Amortized O(1)
         std::push_heap(elems.begin(), elems.end()); // O(logN)
    }
    void pop() {
         std::pop_heap(elems.begin(), elems.end());  // O(logN)
         elems.pop_back(); // O(1)
    }
}
```

Compare with your suggestion

```
template <typename T>
class priority_queue
{
    std::vector<T> elems;
public:
    std::vector<T>::const_reference top() const { 
         return elems.back(); // O(1)
    }
    void push( const T& value ) { 
         std::vector<T>::iterator pos = std::lower_bound(elems.begin(), elems.end(), std::greater<>{}); // O(logN)
         elems.insert(pos, value); // O(N)
    }
    void pop() {
         elems.pop_back(); // O(1)
    }
}
```

Comment: `top()` should actually return `elems.front()`.

Comment: I was referencing the first snippet, not the second one. You effectively `pop_back()`, but the element you `pop` is actually the element that was at the `front()` of the vector before `pop_heap` because `pop_heap` first swap `front()` and `back()`, and then move the old `back()` at the correct position in the vector.